# Printing Access many reports with one click

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I've an Access app generating many reports, I made a command button to print some reports by one click.
The problem is: I'm using `Cancel = True` if a report has no data so, the printing process terminated & not complete the rest of reports.
Any advice?

Below is a sample code to create reports as pdf & save it on a folder

```
Private Sub Savetopdf_Click()

Dim ReportPath As String
Dim CompanyLogo As String
Dim MyWhere As String
Dim ReportOutput As String
Dim ReportName As String
ReportPath = DLookup("AttachentsPath", "emailElements")

ReportName = "Report1"
MyWhere = "[Type] IN ('Type1','Type3','Type4','Type6') and [Company] IN ('Company1', 'Company2') and [Status] In ('Active')"
    CompanyLogo = "'Company1','Company2'"
    ReportOutput = "Report1 Comp1&Comp2"
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , MyWhere, acHidden, CompanyLogo
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, ReportPath & ReportOutput & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
    
MyWhere = "[Type] IN ('Type1','Type3','Type4','Type6') and [Company] IN ('Company3') and [Status] In ('Active')"
    CompanyLogo = "'Company3'"
    ReportOutput = "Report1 Comp3"
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , MyWhere, acHidden, CompanyLogo & "|"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, ReportPath & ReportOutput & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName

ReportName = "Report2"
MyWhere = "[Type] IN ('Type1','Type3','Type4','Type6') and [Company] IN ('Company1', 'Company2') and [Status] In ('Active')"
    CompanyLogo = "'Company1','Company2'"
    ReportOutput = "Report2 Comp1&Comp2"
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , MyWhere, acHidden, CompanyLogo & "|"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, ReportPath & ReportOutput & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
                
MyWhere = "[Type] IN ('Type1','Type3','Type4','Type6') and [Company] IN ('Company3') and [Status] In ('Active')"
    CompanyLogo = "'Company3'"
    ReportOutput = "Report2 Comp3"
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , MyWhere, acHidden, CompanyLogo & "|"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, ReportPath & ReportOutput & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't set `Cancel = True` at all. Instead use an `IF` statement to check if a report has data and print only if True.

Comment: Example of the code is needed to see what happens when you click the button.

Comment: @KostasK. if a report has no data don't print. which expression can be used to not print the empty report & continue the other printing processes?

Comment: @MathiasZ  as an example : `ReportPath = "The Path"  
ReportName = "The Name"  
MyWhere = " . . ." 'Where condition  
ReportOutput = "file name"  
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , MyWhere, acHidden  
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, ReportPath & ReportOutput & ".pdf"  
DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName`

Comment: Hello Ashraf, could you add a print screen of the code ? The best thing to do is limit the query behind the report so it doesn't return blanc record == blanc reports. This way , all reports will print because they will all have data.

Comment: @MathiasZ actually, some of these reports may have no data on the printing time (reports are depending on activities on the printing time) and it is not required to be printed except it contains data.

Comment: I would suggest this approach : Create a table called tzzReports , in this table you create a record for each report you want to print. You can use the command button in your form for this. Then you can use this as a recordsource for the selected reports. In this case a record exists for every report you wish to print, i strongly recommend following an approach where there is data for everything you wish to 'show'.

Comment: Edit your question to show relevant code as formatted text, not image. How does that code print 'many reports'?

Comment: Best is for recordset to not include values that will call a report with no data.

Comment: @June7 The reports are generated based on a filter form (contains about 20 conditions) the where condition is used to open the report in addition there are 2 open arguments, weekly one user has to generate 9 specific reports & send it his boss so, he generate these reports & save it as pdf then attache it to an email. I used a static where condition whith his 9 criterias to open the reports & save it as pdf in a folder then attach all files to an email with To:,subject & body - everything is working fine excpt if a report has no data the operation terminated & not completed the rest of reports

Comment: @MathiasZ Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @AshrafFouad, I know what you want and my comment is the same. Otherwise, need code in procedure that will check if report will have data then proceed accordingly. One way to do this check is with DLookup() using the same criteria applied to report. Again, edit question with relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You are right @june7 I used Dlookup to the report based query with the criteria.

```
ReportName = "Report1"
MyWhere = "[Type] IN ('Type1','Type3','Type4','Type6') and [Company] IN ('Company1', 'Company2') and [Status] In ('Active')"
If DLookup("[ID]", "[Reportq]", MyWhere) <> "" Then  'added
    CompanyLogo = "'Company1','Company2'"
    ReportOutput = "Report1 Comp1&Comp2"
    DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , MyWhere, acHidden, CompanyLogo
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, ReportPath & ReportOutput & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
End If
'''
```